# sigma.js doesn't display networks in django

Tags: json, django, sigma.js

i am using sigma.js to display my gene interaction networks. the codes shows here.

```
var g = {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
    }; s = new sigma({
graph: g,
container: 'network',
renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('network'),
    type: 'canvas'
},
settings: {
    minNodeSize: 8,
    maxNodeSize: 16
}  }); sigma.parsers.json(
    'data.json',
    s,
    function() {
        var i,
                nodes = s.graph.nodes(),
                len = nodes.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            nodes[i].x = Math.random();
            nodes[i].y = Math.random();
            nodes[i].size = s.graph.degree(nodes[i].id);
            nodes[i].color = nodes[i].center ? '#333' : '#666';
        }

        s.refresh();

        s.startForceAtlas2();
    } );
```

data.json is my nodes and edges file. it works well on a apache server.

the problem is when i testing these codes with django. i put above codes in django template file,  the url is `url(r'^show/(\d{1,4})/$', show),`. when i starting a server with "python manage.py runserver", it doesn't work and display errors like 
"[18/Jun/2016 16:01:15] "GET /show/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4383
 [18/Jun/2016 16:01:16] "GET /show/4/data.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2069".

i guess there is not a view to deal with data.json and changed the url to  `url(r'^show/(\d{1,4})/(.*)/$', show)` , but failed, it doesn't work, too.

To deal with this problem, i write a json in "view.py" and {{ json_str | safe}} in template tag, when i send my data 'json_str=json.dumps(data)' to template, i get a error message in url.

`[18/Jun/2016 16:15:17] "GET /show/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4706`
[18/Jun/2016 16:15:19] "GET /show/4/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 404 2093`

i need some help, can anybody give me some tips here?

Answer (score 0):

First do you need a template?

Yes: You can put this in `<script>` tag.

No: You get json via ajax 
in you view.py

```
return JsonResponse
```

[JsonResponse objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)